# Symfony 2 Bind data from a form to an entity WITHOUT form component

Tags: forms, validation, symfony

I´d like to use Symfony 2 Validation Component to validate my forms without using form component as I prefer to create my own HTML forms manually. How can I do to bind the data from my manual form to an entity so that I can validate that entity in the controller?

Comment: Well you would basically go through $_POST and do a bunch of $entity->setWhatever.  Kind of a pain.  I think you will find that using the form component easier.  It's also quite easy to customize the generated html form elements.

Answer (score 3):

Just go through the `$request->request` parameter bag and use the setters of your model to set the data. Then you can use the `validator` service to validate the entity:

```php
$constraintViolationList = $this->get('validator')->validate($entity);
```

If `$constraintViolationList` is not empty, the entity is not valid.

BTW, I believe that the Symfony form component is arguably the greatest part of the framework. I suggest you reconsider your position about it.

Comment: Ok, I will think about it. The problem that I see to form components is related to designers, I mean; designer work better if the code is pure HTML.

Comment: There are two layers in the form component: the holding/binding/validating one and the rendering one. The designers will still have ways to customize forms rendering.